# Can I make this trigger shorter / better / faster?

Tags: sql-server

The task itself is very basic. I have a transaction table that moves a certain quantity of a product in or out of stock. It becomes a bit more difficult knowing that a product can be composed from multiple 'base' products and only the base products may exist in stock.

My current trigger works but works like this:

1. Create temporary table that can combine inserted, deleted and composed products.
2. Add inserted non composed products to this temp table
3. Add inserted composed products
4. Subtract deleted non composed products
5. Subtract deleted composed products

I now have a table containing all transactions of non composed products. But i.e. with an update of a row, the same product is added twice. Once subtracting the old value and once adding the new value.

6. Create second temporary table for the joined non composed products
7. Take a sum of the products and put these into the new temp table
8. Merge the stock with this temp table

Again.. my trigger works fine and i'm having no performance problem (yet) but I feel i'm missing something. I bet there is someone around here with a better solution then mine.

My tables and sample data: ([fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ecd73e))

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [plantId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [reference] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [composed] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [unit] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [dateUpdate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product] VALUES (2, 'FILLER VULPROF 2 BR', 0, 'FILLER VULPROF 2 BR', 'ton', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product] VALUES (2, 'K 0/2GEW BR', 0, 'K 0/2GEW BR', 'ton', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product] VALUES (2, 'K 14/20 BR', 0, 'K 14/20 BR', 'ton', GETDATE());
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product] VALUES (2, 'KWS BR 3A31', 1, 'KWS BR 3A31', 'ton', GETDATE());

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductComposition](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [productId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [parentId] [int] NOT NULL,  -- This is the parent product
    [quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
    [dateUpdate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductComposition] VALUES (1, 4, 0.001, GETDATE());
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductComposition] VALUES (3, 4, 0.001, GETDATE());

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [load] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [plantId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [vehicleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [productId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [contactId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
    [dateUpdate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [isSynched] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Transaction_isSynched]  DEFAULT ((0))
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stock](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [plantId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [productId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
    [dateUpdate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
);
```

My Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[StockCalculate]
ON [dbo].[Transaction]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 

BEGIN
    -- Create temporary table
    CREATE TABLE #TransactionsComposed (
        [load] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [plantId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [productId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [quantity] [float] NOT NULL
    );

    -- Insert basic materials
    INSERT INTO #TransactionsComposed (
        [load], [plantId], [productId], [quantity])
    SELECT 
        [Inserted].[load], 
        [Inserted].[plantId],
        [Inserted].[productId],
        [Inserted].[quantity]
    FROM 
        [Inserted]
        INNER JOIN [Product] ON [Product].[id] = [Inserted].[productId]
    WHERE 
        [Product].[composed] = 0;

    -- Insert operations
    INSERT INTO #TransactionsComposed (
        [load], [plantId], [productId], [quantity])
    SELECT 
        [Inserted].[load], 
        [Inserted].[plantId], 
        [ProductComposition].[productId], 
        ([Inserted].[quantity] * [ProductComposition].[quantity])
    FROM 
        [Inserted]
        INNER JOIN [Product] ON [Product].[id] = [Inserted].[productId]
        INNER JOIN [ProductComposition] ON [ProductComposition].[parentId] = [Product].[id]
    WHERE 
        [Product].[composed] = 1;

    -- Insert basic materials but ALTER it's load status.
    INSERT INTO #TransactionsComposed (
        [load], [plantId], [productId], [quantity])
    SELECT 
        CASE [Deleted].[load] 
            WHEN 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN 1 THEN 0 
        END,
        [Deleted].[plantId], 
        [Deleted].[productId],
        [Deleted].[quantity]
    FROM 
        [Deleted]
        INNER JOIN [Product] ON [Product].[id] = [Deleted].[productId]
    WHERE 
        [Product].[composed] = 0;

    -- Insert operations but ALTER it's load status.
    INSERT INTO #TransactionsComposed (
        [load], [plantId], [productId], [quantity])
    SELECT 
        CASE [Deleted].[load] 
            WHEN 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN 1 THEN 0 
        END,
        [Deleted].[plantId], 
        [ProductComposition].[productId], 
        ([Deleted].[quantity] * [ProductComposition].[quantity])
    FROM 
        [Deleted]
        INNER JOIN [Product] ON [Product].[id] = [Deleted].[productId]
        INNER JOIN [ProductComposition] ON [ProductComposition].[parentId] = [Product].[id]
    WHERE 
        [Product].[composed] = 1;


    -- Prepare multiple products for merge
    CREATE TABLE #TransactionsJoined (
        [plantId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [productId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [quantity] [float] NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO #TransactionsJoined
        ([plantId], [productId], [quantity])
    SELECT
        [plantId],
        [productId],
        SUM(CASE [load]
                WHEN 0 THEN [quantity]
                WHEN 1 THEN 0 - [quantity]
            END)
    FROM
        #TransactionsComposed
    GROUP BY [plantId], [productId]


    -- Merge composed transactions into the stock
    MERGE [Stock]
    USING #TransactionsJoined
    ON [Stock].[plantId]=#TransactionsJoined.[plantId]
    AND [Stock].[productId]=#TransactionsJoined.[productId]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
        INSERT ([plantId], [productId], [quantity]) 
        VALUES (
            #TransactionsJoined.[plantId], 
            #TransactionsJoined.[productId], 
            #TransactionsJoined.[quantity])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET
            [Stock].[quantity] = [Stock].[quantity] + #TransactionsJoined.[quantity],
            [Stock].[dateUpdate] = GETDATE();
END
```

Comment: You probably can. However, it's not very easy to read your sample data (while it's great that you posted the DDL+DML for it!) and your desired outcome is also not so clear. Please consider editing your question (and refrain from calling us smartasses if you want anybody's help) to make it clearer.

Comment: That wasn't meant as an insult ;-) I tried to keep the question as short and clean as possible. Using the example data you can add a Transaction and the result will be visible in the Stock table. Any tips on how to clarify?